# Haskell type system nuances

Tags: class, haskell, types, system

I've been getting into the nitty gritty of the haskell typesystem and trying to get at the fine points of type classes. I've learned a heap, but I'm hitting a wall on the following pieces of code.

Using these Class and Instance definitions:

```
class Show a => C a where
  f :: Int -> a

instance C Integer where
  f x = 1

instance C Char where
  f x = if x < 10 then 'c' else 'd'
```

Why is it that this passes the type checker:

```
g :: C a => a -> Int -> a
g x y = f y

yes :: C a => a -> Int -> String
yes x y = show (g x y)
```

but this doesn't?

```
g :: C a => a -> Int -> String
g x y = show(f y)
```

I find the second alternative much more readable, and it seems to be only a minor difference (note the type signatures). However, trying to get that past the typechecker results in:

```
*Main> :l typetests.hs
[1 of 1] Compiling Main             ( typetests.hs, interpreted )

typetests.hs:11:14:
    Ambiguous type variable `a0' in the constraints:
      (C a0) arising from a use of `f' at typetests.hs:11:14
      (Show a0) arising from a use of `show' at typetests.hs:11:9-12
    Probable fix: add a type signature that fixes these type variable(s)
    In the first argument of `show', namely `(f y)'
    In the expression: show (f y)
    In an equation for `g': g x y = show (f y)
Failed, modules loaded: none.
```

And I don't understand why.

Note: Please don't ask "What are you trying to do?" I would hope it is obvious that I'm just messing around in an abstract context in order to probe the way this language works. I have no goal in mind other than learning something new.

Thanks

Comment: Bloody hell! First post on SO and I get three great and insightful answers in less than 24 hours. This place is amazing. Thanks guys

Answer (score 22, accepted):

This is where a fun toy comes into play.  Consider the standard Prelude function `asTypeOf`.

```
asTypeOf :: a -> a -> a
asTypeOf = const
```

It just returns its first argument, no matter what the second argument is.  But the type signature on it places the additional constraint that both of its arguments must be the same type.

```
g :: C a => a -> Int -> String
g x y = show (f y `asTypeOf` x)
```

Now, GHC knows what the type of `f y` is.  It's the same as the type of the first argument to `g`.  Without that information, well, you get the error message you saw.  There just wasn't sufficient information to determine the type of `f y`.  And because the type is important (it's used to determine which instance to use for `show`), GHC needs to know what type you mean to generate code.

Answer (score 21):

This is a variant of the notorious `show . read` problem. The classic version uses

```
read :: Read a => String -> a
show :: Show a => a -> String
```

so the composition might seem to be a plain old String transducer

```
moo :: String -> String
moo = show . read
```

except that there is no information in the program to determine the type in the middle, hence what to `read` and then `show`.

```
Ambiguous type variable `b' in the constraints:
  `Read b' arising from a use of `read' at ...
  `Show b' arising from a use of `show' at ...
Probable fix: add a type signature that fixes these type variable(s)
```

Please not that ghci does a bunch of crazy extra defaulting, resolving ambiguity arbitrarily.

```
> (show . read) "()"
"()"
```

Your `C` class is a variant of `Read`, except that it decodes an `Int` instead of reading a `String`, but the problem is essentially the same.

Type system enthusiasts will note that underconstrained type variables are not *per se* a big deal. It's ambiguous *instance inference* that's the issue here. Consider

```
poo :: String -> a -> a
poo _ = id

qoo :: (a -> a) -> String
qoo _ = ""

roo :: String -> String
roo = qoo . poo
```

In the construction of `roo`, it is never determined what the type in the middle must be, nor is `roo` polymorphic in that type. Type inference neither solves nor generalizes the variable! Even so,

```
> roo "magoo"
""
```

it's not a problem, because the construction is *parametric* in the unknown type. The fact that the type cannot be determined has the consequence that the type cannot *matter*.

But unknown *instances* clearly do matter. The completeness result for Hindley-Milner type inference relies on parametricity and is thus lost when we add overloading. Let us not weep for it.

Answer (score 16):

In

```
g :: C a => a -> Int -> a
g x y = f y
```

the return type of `f y` is fixed by the type signature, so that if you call, e.g. `g 'a' 3`, `instance C Char` will be used. But in

```
g :: C a => a -> Int -> String
g x y = show(f y)
```

there are two constraints on return type of `f`: it must be an instance of `C` (so that `f` can be used) and of `Show` (so that `show` can be used). And that's all! Coincidence of type variable names `a` in definitions of `f` and `g` doesn't mean anything. So the compiler has no way to choose between `instance C Char` and `instance C Integer` (or any instances defined in other modules, so removing these instances won't make the program compile).