# What happens to missing type variables in Church-style core?

Tags: haskell, types

This is a bit esoteric, but maddening. In an answer to [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7074322/haskell-type-system-nuances), I noted that in this entirely valid program

```
poo :: String -> a -> a
poo _ = id

qoo :: (a -> a) -> String
qoo _ = ""

roo :: String -> String
roo = qoo . poo
```

the type variable `a` is neither solved nor generalized in the process of checking `roo`. I'm wondering what happens in the translation to GHC's core language, a Church-style variant of System F. Let me spell things out longhand, with explicit type lambdas `/\` and type applications `@`.

```
poo :: forall a. [Char] -> a -> a
poo = /\ a -> \ s x -> id @ a

qoo :: forall a. (a -> a) -> [Char]
qoo = /\ a -> \ f -> [] @ Char

roo :: [Char] -> [Char]
roo = (.) @ [Char] @ (? -> ?) @ [Char] (qoo @ ?) (poo @ ?)
```

What on earth goes in the `?` places? How does `roo` become a valid core term? Or do we really get a mysterious vacuous quantifier, despite what the type signature says?

```
roo :: forall a. [Char] -> [Char]
roo = /\ a -> ...
```

I've just checked that

```
roo :: forall . String -> String
roo = qoo . poo
```

goes through ok, which may or may not mean that the thing typechecks with no extra quantification.

What's happening down there?

Comment: Try to make clear to yourself how the expression ((const "" . const id) "foo") is typed and you'll be enlightened.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Here's the core generated by GHC (after adding some `NOINLINE` pragmas).

```
qoo_rbu :: forall a_abz. (a_abz -> a_abz) -> GHC.Base.String
[GblId, Arity=1, Caf=NoCafRefs]
qoo_rbu = \ (@ a_abN) _ -> GHC.Types.[] @ GHC.Types.Char

poo_rbs :: forall a_abA. GHC.Base.String -> a_abA -> a_abA
[GblId, Arity=1]
poo_rbs = \ (@ a_abP) _ -> GHC.Base.id @ a_abP

roo_rbw :: GHC.Base.String -> GHC.Base.String
[GblId]
roo_rbw =
  GHC.Base..
    @ (GHC.Prim.Any -> GHC.Prim.Any)
    @ GHC.Base.String
    @ GHC.Base.String
    (qoo_rbu @ GHC.Prim.Any)
    (poo_rbs @ GHC.Prim.Any)
```

It seems `GHC.Prim.Any` is used for the polymorphic type.

From [the docs](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/7.2-latest/html/libraries/ghc-prim-0.2.0.0/GHC-Prim.html#t:Any) (emphasis mine):

> The type constructor `Any` is type to which you can unsafely coerce any
>   lifted type, and back.
>
> - It is lifted, and hence represented by a pointer
> - It does not claim to
>     be a data type, and that's important for the code generator, because
>     the code gen may enter a data value but never enters a function value.
>
> It's also **used to instantiate un-constrained type variables after type
>   checking.**

It makes sense to have such a type to insert in place of un-constrained types, as otherwise trivial expressions like `length []` would cause an ambiguous type error.

Comment: I guess that's about as principled a bodge as we can hope for. Parametricity is critical to its harmlessness. It's a "don't care" dummy.

Comment: Could you provide information on how we could generate the information you provided ourselves?

Comment: @ocharles: The core? `ghc -ddump-simpl`.

Answer (score 0):

This is a non-problem. In the signature of  *roo*, the type variable a just does not appear as it stands. An easier example would be the expression

```
const 1 id
```

where

```
id :: forall a.a->a
```

Comment: Given the types of `poo` and `qoo`, how do you get that type for roo? (GHCi agrees with me.) It's the type of `poo` that's restricted, but I could certainly rewrite it to have that type inferred. Of course it's not a problem once you've erased the type information. But if your intermediate language is explicit about type abstraction and application, you need some way to account for type variables that are unconstrained. It appears that a dummy is used.

Comment: Yes, you're right, the type is indeed String -> String. The type variable a is just any type and, as it happens, never instantiated. It's the same like in (const 1 id), where id :: forall a.a -> a, again a is never instantiated.