# Haskell polymorphic calls without complete type knowledge

Tags: haskell, types, polymorphism

I'm studying Haskell since a little while, so I'm a newbie.

The following code is very easily understandable:

```
purStrLn $ show [1]
```

Here we can infer all the types (with defaults), and all works well.
But the following code works, too:

```
putStrLn $ show []
```

even if we can't infer the list type.

If I execute the code with ghci I obtain the following:

```
Prelude> []
[]
Prelude> :t it
it :: [a]
Prelude>
```

so the type seems to be polymorphic. But in this case the show would be called with a partially applied type.

The same behavior is common with other types, for example with Data.Map.empty, so it isn't a list feature (or at least it seems like it).

Why and how it works?

Comment: `purStrLn $ show [1]` still has to default to a type, as `[1] :: (Num n) => [n]`

Comment: That's true, but there are defaults in cases like this.

Comment: Note that something else happens when the type variable is unconstrained like in e.g. `length []`, see: http://stackoverflow.com/q/7076517.

Comment: @hammar That's very interesting! I've to gain a deeper understanding, that's for sure!

Answer (score 16, accepted):

First of all, this works only in `ghci`. If you try to compile this program with `ghc` you'll get a type error:

```
Test.hs:3:19:
    Ambiguous type variable `a0' in the constraint:
      (Show a0) arising from a use of `show'
    Probable fix: add a type signature that fixes these type variable(s)
    In the second argument of `($)', namely `show []'
    In the expression: putStrLn $ show []
    In an equation for `main': main = putStrLn $ show []
```

Adding a type signature makes the error go away:

```
module Main where

main = putStrLn $ show ([]::[Int])
```

But why did it work in `ghci`? The answer is [extended type defaulting](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/7.6.2/html/users_guide/interactive-evaluation.html#extended-default-rules) in `ghci`: the type of `a` is defaulted to `()` (the unit type).

The motivation for this behaviour is that it is a bit tiresome for the user to always specify the types when working in the interpreter. As Vitus notes in the comments, running `ghci` with `-Wall` (or adding `:set -Wall` to your `~/.ghci`) makes it easier to spot the defaulting:

```
<interactive>:2:12:
    Warning: Defaulting the following constraint(s) to type `()'
               (Show a0) arising from a use of `show'
    In the second argument of `($)', namely `show []'
    In a stmt of an interactive GHCi command: it <- putStrLn $ show []
```

Comment: Also, typing `:set -Wall` in GHCi helps to spot this defaulting.

Comment: Great, it's a very explanatory answer :)